# Bootstrap 3 input issue. keyboard overlapping input fields on Android

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input

I’m using simple modal on my page, with default Bootstrap 3 styles.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <p>Simple form</p>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input1"><span">Old pass</span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="input1" maxlength="20">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input2"><span>New pass</span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="input2" maxlength="20">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button">change pass</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

When input in focus and keyboard up, it’s overlapping input fields. It is necessary to scroll form to see what typing. It's not good.
how to correct this form behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the focus to your input. That might force WebView to scroll into "visible" view.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#input1').focus();
})
```

Comment: didn't work. keyboard up when modal opened and overlapping field. perhaps it happens because .modal have fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Mark I was working on this today and wanted to give my solution.

```
  .modal{
     position: sticky;
    }
```

I was working with a MEAN stack application, and the file i was manipulating was an EJS file so your experience may differ! Hope that helps! Here is a bit more detailed code it could have been a combo of styles but this is most of the css file.

```
html
    {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        body {
            padding-top: 100px;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .scrollable{
          position: inherit;
        }
        .image{
          position: fixed;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          background-image: url("Login-Image.png");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          opacity: 0.7;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        .form-container {
            width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .login-style{
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 999;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding-left: 25%;
            padding-right: 25%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```